# How to use the empirically derived increment for shell sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, shellsort

As per the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) article, I am trying to implement Shell sort with the empirically derived increments to perform the h-sort:

```
1,4,10,23,57,132,301,701
```

Presently, I am using `h = 3*h + 1` to perform the sort, here is my implementation:

```
    public class Solution
{
    private static final int arr[] = {9,4,5,1,2,8,7,6,12,45,21,34,1,2,3};
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N = arr.length;
        int h = 1;
        while(h<N/3)
            h = 3*h + 1;
        while(h>=1)
        {
            for(int i=h;i<N;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i;j>=h && arr[j-h]>arr[j];j-=h)
                {
                    int temp = arr[j-h];
                    arr[j-h] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            h/=3;
        }

        for(int x:arr)
            System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

Now, this does the task well. But the question is, if I were to implement the shell sort by using the empirically derived sequence to perform the h sort, how should I choose which increment I must use based on the size of array?

Comment: use the min-function together with the length of the array to avoid out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store empirically derived sequence in array and find the last element of this array that is smaller than data array size.

For example, if data size is 500, you have to get 301 as the first step

Comment: Will that be the optimal solution?

Comment: That will be very good solution. Shell sort analysis is very hard. One could find the best step sequence for given data size, but cited sequence works well in common case.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, one more doubt, is this empirical sequence faster than, h = 3*h + 1

Comment: This sequence has been experimentally found by Marcin Ciura as good in average for some range of data size. You can also use better explored Sedgewick sequence from the code here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/shell/paperF.pdf

Comment: Sedgewick paper mentions 3n+1 sequence as Knuth's one, and says that ratio about 2.2 is better than 3 (while 3n+1 is still rather good for practical use).